# `overflow:hidden` not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok!! I am facing weird issue that `overflow:hidden` is not working in FF.

> **Problem**: On opening modal window, parent page scrolls to top.

To fix this, i have used below solution

**CSS**

```
.removeBodyScroll{
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both
}
```

**JS**

```
$("ul#list li").off("click").on("click", function () {
    if ($(".dialog-popup-open").length > 0) {
        $('html,body').addClass("removeBodyScroll");
       console.log($('html,body').hasClass("removeBodyScroll"));
    }
});
```

The above solution works perfectly in Chrome and **MOST AMAZINGLY IN IE also**.

But this time FF is irritating. The modal window shifts the parent content to top :(  .. Help please.

Comment: Have you detached the modal from the textflow?

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: Setting `position: fixed` for the modal takes it away from the textflow, and it won't affect to the rest of the page.

Comment: Please post a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: `position:fixed` is not also working...

Comment: Please post some code with which we can reproduce your issue, or create a fiddle as akash has suggested.

Comment: Fiddle is something that is not possible for this code. i usually create wherever i can. but now when i remove this code then i am seeing double scroll bars on page

Comment: Notice, that in my comment I said: "_fixed for the modal_", not `html, body`.

Comment: Why someone has downvoted?? please mention reason here